# No sound after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, sound-card

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and now have no sound. This seems to be a common problem, but the answers on the Ubuntu forums aren't working for me.

```
#> aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

I tried this

```
apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
```

I tried this

```
modprobe snd-usb-audio
modprobe snd-hda-intel
```

I also reinstalled the kernel.

I tried following [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iTlJ8BfqXUjaHO__TEdlkvuqB1WLOkGaudngc5SFLMI/edit#), the `speaker-test` produces "Playback device is default" output and seems to think it's working but there is no actual sound, then the guide directs me to procedure Ac which tells me to run this

> `echo "Sound cards recognized by the system:"; lspci -nn | grep --color=none '\[04[80][13]\]'; echo "Sound cards recognized by ALSA:"; lspci -nn | grep '\[04[80][13]\]' | while read line; do lspci -nnk | grep -A 3 '\[04[80][13]\]' | grep -e 'Kernel modules: ..*' -e '\[04[80][13]\]' | grep --color=none -F "$line"; done; echo "Sound cards recognized by ALSA, and activated:"; lspci -nn | grep '\[04[80][13]\]' | while read line; do lspci -nnk | grep -A 3 '\[04[80][13]\]' | grep -e 'Kernel drivers in use: ..*' -e '\[04[80][13]\]' | grep --color=none -F "$line"; done`

which gives this output

```
Sound cards recognized by the system:
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
Sound cards recognized by ALSA:
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
Sound cards recognized by ALSA, and activated:
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
```

This seems to be in order but `aplay -l` still says "no soundcards" and there is still no actual sound.

```
#> ls /dev/snd
by-path  controlC0  hwC0D0  hwC0D3  pcmC0D0c  pcmC0D0p  pcmC0D1c  pcmC0D1p  pcmC0D2c  pcmC0D3p  pcmC0D4c  pcmC0D7p  pcmC0D8p  seq  timer
```

There is no `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-alsa.conf`

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, in a very similar situation (replace '*user*' with your username):

```
sudo setfacl -m u:*user*:rw /dev/snd/*
```

credit : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2234109